# Multiprocessing.Pool() stuck

Tags: python, multiprocessing, deadlock

I'm in a situation where a function `func` is applied to a long list. This is done using something equivalent to

```
long_list_processed = Pool().map(func, long_list)
```

This spawns exactly `os.cpu_count()` processes.
This piece of code is called 10 times, but according parent processes only finish (unsystematically) 6-8 times. The rest is stuck forever - deadlock.

I can't get around why a deadlock happens here (there is no shared state in any way here). Also, would it be better to limit the number of processes per Pool() to avoid context switches?

EDIT:The func() is roughly the following:

```
def check_contains(linestring, polygon): 
    if linestring.within(polygon): 
        return linestring 
    return None
```

So, checking if a Shapely linestring is contained in a polygon.

Comment: can you share a little bit more code that will help to reproduce?

Comment: You need to share your `func()`. The problem is not in Pool implementation - it is robust - but in the code you feed to it or the way you use it.

Comment: Thanks. I unfortunately couldn't reproduce in a simple way. To give more context, I added what the func() function is doing. As Pool() only handles one argument, I convert the above function with the partial library first (polygon is a constant).

Answer (score 2):

There's too few details to give a better answer, but if `func` writes to a log or something similar, this might be the problem.

> 1. Whenever the thread in the parent process writes a log messages, it adds it to a Queue. That involves acquiring a lock.
> 2. If the fork() happens at the wrong time, the lock is copied in an acquired state.
> 3. The child process copies the parent’s logging configuration—including the queue.
> 4. Whenever the child process writes a log message, it tries to write it to the queue.
> 5. That means acquiring the lock, but the lock is already acquired.
> 6. The child process now waits for the lock to be released.
> 7. The lock will never be released, because the thread that would release it wasn’t copied over by the fork().

Source: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/